# Loading dynamic photos on flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing a news app and in some matters there is a gallery of photos and I need to upload these photos at the end of the story, but I am having difficulty passing the data between the functions and retrieving them in the carousel.

_getFotos (_id) and loadFotos are responsible for bringing the data and in the class ImageCarousel and Widget build (BuildContext context) I mount the whole scope of the carousel, which is working, just need to leave dynamic and check if there is photo in the news, if there is displayed, or mount the carousel. How can I redeem the data and make the photos dynamic?

Print carousel https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4b6F.png

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:news/localization/MyLocalizations.dart';
import 'package:news/util/date_util.dart';
import 'package:news/util/functions.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import "dart:convert";
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';

import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
const requestNotice = "${url}api/v1/noticias/fotos/";

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget{
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =  Completer<WebViewController>();
  var _img;
  var _video_id;
  var _title;
  var _date;
  var _description;
  var _link;
  var _category;
  var _origin;
  var img;
  var _id;
  var _status;
  DetailPage(this._img,this._video_id,this._title,this._date,this._description,this._category,this._link,this._origin,this._id, this._status);
  MyLocalizations strl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    strl = MyLocalizations.of(context);
    // Chama a função das fotos e passa o id da notícia
   _getFotos(_id);

      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(_category),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () {
                shareNotice();
              },
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
  }

    // Várias funções aqui

 _getFotos(id) async {
   loadFotos(id);
   var fotos = await this.loadFotos(id);
   print(fotos);
   return fotos;
 }

  Future shareNotice() async {
    await Share.share("$_title:\n$_link");
  }







  Future<String>loadFotos(id) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(requestNotice + (id));
    var fotos = json.decode(response.body);
    return fotos;
  }







}







class ImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  _ImageCarouselState createState() => new _ImageCarouselState();
}

class _ImageCarouselState extends State<ImageCarousel> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    animation = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 18.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // the state that has changed here is the animation object’s value
        });
      });
    controller.forward();
  }







  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          child: Carousel(
                boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                images: [
                  AssetImage('assets/1.jpeg'),
                  AssetImage('assets/2.jpeg'),
                  AssetImage('assets/3.jpeg'),
                  AssetImage('assets/4.jpeg'),
                ],
                animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds:2000),
          )
        )
    );
  }

  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need to send the request all over again every certain time. You can use a **Timer** or a **Stream.periodic** for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can already load the necessary data, I am only in doubt of how to rescue them in the last  @override and insert insert the images